# QGIS drawing segment of azimuth from values defined

Tags: qgis, buffer, expression, azimuth

I have the range of azimuth defined in the data attribute table as you see below:
[image]

And as a result, I want to have some visual section of the bearing, determined by the azimuth I and azimuth II values in my data attribute table.

Is it possible in QGIS?

Comment: Do you mean 'as depicted in the linked image' ?

Comment: yes, i want something like shown in the image,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`wedge_buffer()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?#wedge-buffer) with [Geometry generator or Geometry by expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814) and this expression:

```
wedge_buffer( 
    $geometry, 
    azimuth1+(azimuth2-azimuth1)/2,
    azimuth2-azimuth1,
    10000
)
```

To change the size (radius), adapt the number on the 2nd last line (here: `10000`). [See here for details](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?#wedge-buffer).

When working with angles, be sure to use an appropriate CRS (one that preserves angles like Mercator projection) - see 2nd screenshot.

[image]

*Difference between `EPSG:4326` (blue) and `EPSG:3857` (red), using the same expression:*

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works. How to restrict it to a few kilometers instead of a whole globe? The range is endless now.

Comment: You probably used a geographic CRS with units in degrees, that's why it gets so huge. See updated answer how to change that. Howver, be aware: when working with angles, best use a CRS that returns equal angles. So here, a mercator projection is a good option (I used WebMercator / `EPSG:3857`).